# Swift date string to Date fails when milliseconds has fractional value (value other than 000)

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

I have some weird situation here

I am trying to convert my dateString to Date, it is failing whenever my date has fractional milliseconds (value more than 000)

```
2019-12-16T10:23:47.000Z  // works fine 


2019-12-16T10:23:47.673Z // fails
```

here is my String extension

```
extension String {
    func getFormattedDate() -> String {
        let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
        // "2019-12-16T10:23:47.000Z"
        dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ" 

        let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yy" 


        let date: Date? = dateFormatterGet.date(from: self) 
        // here date value returns nil when i have fractional milliseconds

        print("Date",dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date!)) // prints 16-12-19


        //it fails in below line saying "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping 
        // an Optional value" as date returns nil
        return dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date!); 
    }
   }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use  `SSS` for fractional seconds, not `sss`.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier for milliseconds is `SSS`, but you have used `sss`, which caused the parsing to be failed.

You can fix this by using the correct format:

```
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Or, since the format is ISO 8601 anyway, you can use a `ISO8601DateFormatter`:

```
let dateFormatterGet = ISO8601DateFormatter()
// you only need the date, so only withFullDate
dateFormatterGet.formatOptions = [.withFullDate] 
// if you need to parse everything, you need the following options:
// [.withFullDate, .withFullTime, .withFractionalSeconds, .withTimeZone]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```